# how to extract nested html element to same level in js

Tags: javascript, html

I use javascript and have a div element with some html tags inside it like below, some of the elements are nested and I want to keep them in the same level, first html is like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>
    some text on here 1
    <i>
      some italic 
      <b>text</b>
      here
    </i> text text text
  </p>
  <b>
    some bold text on here
  </b>
</div>
```

I don't know how I can extract those nested elements and keep them on the same level, something like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>
    some text on here 1
  </p>
  <i>
    some italic 
  </i>
  <b>text</b>
  <i>
    here
  </i>
  <p>
    text text text
  </p>
  <b>
    some bold text on here
  </b>
</div>
```

### update 1

The performance of the code is not too important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone original node using `.cloneNode()` with parameter `true`; iterate the `.childNodes` of parent `<div>`, if node `.previousElementSibling` is not `null` and `.parentElement` is not original parent element passed to function push `.parentElement` `.tagName` and `.textContent` to array, else `.nodeName` is `#text`, push `.textContent` to an array; if `.nodeName` does not equal `#text` and only `#text` nodes exist within element, push `.outerHTML` to array; if node `.tagName` does not equal `#text` and node `.firstChild` node is `#text`, push node `.tagName`, `.firstChild` `.textContent`, closing tag to array, remove `.firstChild`; else recursively call function

```js
const clone = document.querySelector("div").cloneNode(true);

let flattenNodes = (el, not = el, res = []) => {
  for (let node of el.childNodes) {
    if (node.nodeName === "#text" && !node.childNodes.length) {
      if (node.previousElementSibling && node.parentElement !== not) {
        let tag = node.parentElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
        res.push(`<${tag}>${node.textContent}</${tag}>`);
      } else {
        res.push(node.textContent);
      }
    }
    if (node.nodeName !== "#text" 
      && Array.from(node.childNodes).every(e => e.nodeName === "#text")) {
        res.push(node.outerHTML);
    } else {
      if (node.tagName && node.tagName !== "#text" 
        && node.firstChild.nodeName === "#text") {
          let tag = node.tagName.toLowerCase();
          res.push(`<${tag}>${node.firstChild.textContent}</${tag}>`);
          node.firstChild.remove();
          flattenNodes(node, not, res);
      }
    }
  }
  return res
}

let res = flattenNodes(clone);

document.querySelector("pre")
.textContent = res.join("");
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    some text on here 1
    <i>
      some italic 
      <b>text</b>
      here
    </i> text text text
  </p>
  <b>
    some bold text on here
  </b>
</div>

<pre></pre>
```

Comment: everything looks ok especially place of the `here` and `text text text` but why this two text is not inside an `<i>` and `<p>` tag ?

Answer (score 1):

How often does this operation need to happen? Is it a performance hazard or is it a rare occasion?

If it's not a bottleneck, you can just select all descendants of your div and append them to the div. When you append an existing node, it will be automatically moved to the appropriate position.

```js
const myDiv = document
      .querySelector('#my-div')

const allDescendants = Array.from(myDiv.getElementsByTagName('*'))

allDescendants.forEach(d => {
  myDiv.appendChild(d);
});

console.log(myDiv.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
  <p>
    some text on here 1
    <i>
      some italic 
      <b>text</b>
      here
    </i> text text text
  </p>
  <b>
    some bold text on here
  </b>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is intentional but based on your example, you only want to move elements and leave other nodes such as text nodes where they were. A specific example is the `here` text portion in the first `<i>`.

To achieve this, you can perform a pre-order DFS through all descendants, and build the new flat tree. Once finished, replace the old element with the new one.

```js
const myDiv = document
      .querySelector('#my-div')

const flatDiv = document.createElement('div')
function recurseAndFlatten(parent) {
  parent.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      flatDiv.appendChild(child);
      recurseAndFlatten(child);
    }
  });
}

recurseAndFlatten(myDiv);

myDiv.replaceWith(flatDiv);

console.log(flatDiv.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
  <p>
    some text on here 1
    <i>
      some italic 
      <b>text</b>
      here
    </i> text text text
  </p>
  <b>
    some bold text on here
  </b>
</div>
```

Comment: Should `"here"` be child of first `<i>` element?

Comment: @guest271314 oh I see, I'm not handling text nodes separately. I'll be back

Comment: @guest271314, no the `here` have to be in a new `<i>` element and place after the bold

Comment: @nem035, thanks to send answer, everything looks good but a little problem with the order and place of nodes like `here` that's you say about it on the comment

Comment: @Mojtaba Would `here` become it's own element if it was on the **same line** as the `<b>` before it? In other words, do child text nodes become a new top-level element only when they come after a new line? Or is it after an element?

Comment: @nem035 child text of a node have to become a new top-level element not because of new line because before that text an element was be, then the `here` text on the `<i>` tag in this example have to become on a new `<i>` tag and place after that `<b>`, and the result of two snippets give me a same result!!!